# I want the "facebook like" div on the top of the page to be on the right side, but it doesn't let me

Tags: html, css

On my site, I want the travelescape "like facebook" box go across the right side of the page but when I add margin it overlaps on something. I also tried doing the z-index and `position:absolute` in css but it didn't work. Do you guys have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: do you have any css class for **LikeboxPluginPagelet** Div??

Answer (score 2):

From the `<iframe>` remove `position:absolute` and `margin-left` and give it a `float:right`.

That solves it for me in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Your better off making a seperate  for it and then adding your facebook div in it.  It happened to me too awhile back book if you look at my site now i got it posistioned under my links .Your not the only one that had a problem for this by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="" align="right" width="50%" class="connect_widget_interactive_area"><tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reducing the width of .name_block and then the following div that contains your like button, and the give float:left !

that should work !

```
 <div class="connect_action">
<div class="name_block">
<div>
```